# Issues With Jade Extends

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Using Jade for the first time in a project. Pretty great so far. It seems that I am having some issues with the **Extends** functionality. My block is not showing up when layout.jade renders.

layout.jade:

```
div.ui.tab.contact(data-tab="contact")
  div.tab-con
    block form
```

index.jade

```
extends layout

block form
  h1 Get in touch...
```

App Configurations:

```
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

The route:

```
app.get('/', index.index);
```

And index.js with the route export:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.render('layout', {});
}
```

I would be more than happy to post any other code. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't render `layout`, Rendering `index` will be ok with your code

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {});
}
```

More over, create the **routes** folder and move `index.js` to **routes**

Example folder structure

```
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── models
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── admin.js
│   │
│   ├── views
│   │   ├── layout.jade
│   │   ├── index.jade
│   │   ├── admin.jade
│
├── public
├── node_modules
```

Comment: "layout.jade" was rendering properly. The blocks that were being added to it were not rendering. I am adjusting my file structure to see if this helps.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin, first, Jade doesn't care about file structure AT ALL. As long as the files are in the same directory everything should work fine. Second, you are *only* rendering the layout. Of course the text in index.jade is not included. This answer is therefore the correct answer, but the file structure part is redundant.